# Autosys job testing

Tags: cron, jobs, autosys

I am new to autosys.. does anyone know how to perform positive and negative test on particluar job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autosys seems to be painfully limited. You can create a condition in JOB2 that depends on the success of JOB1 e.g. SUCCESS(JOB1). But there seems to be no support for a condition that is the inverse of SUCCESS. Autosys provides a RUNNING and a NOTRUNNING condition, but for some reason they unfortunately omitted to include a NOTSUCCESS.

The best workaround I've come up with so far is to use the following JIL configuration:

```
insert_job: 0AM-7AM_BOX
job_type: b
start_times: "00:00"
description: "Succeeds if JOB1 succeeds, TERMINATED if JOB1 does not succeed"
term_run_time: 419

insert_job: CHECK_THE_CONDITION
job_type: c
box_name: 0AM-7AM_BOX
command: date
condition: success(JOB1)
description: "Succeeds if JOB1 succeeds"

insert_job: ACT_ON_THE_CONDITION
job_type: c
command: [put the command you want to execute here]
condition: SUCCESS(CHECK_THE_CONDITION)
description: "Run the run between midnight and 7am if the condition is true"
```

So, if JOB1 enters the state "SUCCESS" between midnight and 7am, then ACT_ON_THE_CONDITION will immediately run. Since the command is just a dummy call to "date" this should run immediately and also become "SUCCESS" and therefore the 0AM-7AM_BOX box will also become "SUCCESS".

The other possibility is that JOB3 does not enter state "SUCCESS" before 7am. In this case, the "term_run_time" setting will cause the box to enter the state "TERMINATED".

Summing up,

1. If JOB1 is SUCCESS, 0AM-7AM_BOX -> SUCCESS
2. If JOB1 is anything except SUCCESS, 0AM-7AM_BOX -> TERMINATED

This is useful because you can then set up dependent jobs that test the success condition or the terminated condition (since TERMINATED is a valid test you can put in a condition).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to test. First get the command or script you want to run working outside of Autosys. As part of that, test the command or scripts error handling. Autosys will report any zero exit code from a a command as a success, so make sure your script sends out a non-zero exit code on any exit from error. Then you can test that the autosys jobs run on schedule by using dummy commands or scripts, like a sleep command. Then you can test using live command or scripts.

To test a particular job, A positive test would be if you force started the job, it ran to sucess and the logs generated by the command ran by autosys indicated that the command was successfull. To do a negative test for a command job would depend on the comand or script being ran. Change something outside of the job to make the command or script fail.